# Problem with Admin CSS after switching from custom path

Tags: admin, adminhtml, javascript, css

We upgraded a client to 1.13EE and removed the custom path in admin. The switch works fine on Local, Dev and Staging.

But on production we are getting this for Admin css (in front of css and js)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="8gTJvKZ1/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
```

I have changed the value in core_config_data to 0 for use custom url and restarted the web server. I grep'd the server for the code 8gTJvKZ1 and could not find it.

EDIT:

I did switch use secure for admin to 0 and now I get this error

```
There has been an error processing your request
Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Got it...

The database also had these values

```
  1751 | stores  |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url       | 8gTJvKZ1/
```

So I should have done

```
select * from core_config_data where value like '%8gTJvKZ1%';
```